# why there are so many chromdriver process during my jmeter running?

Tags: google-chrome, jmeter, selenium-chromedriver

I have jmeter 5.6.2 installed, along with the selenium plug-in. My test case is a to do a login/logout in 2FA mode, to try to check how our server behaves.

In Jmeter, I have set the thread of 20, and loop count of 100. But, when it is being executed, I have seen about ~300 chromdriver processes running during the most execution time, which used up lots of my system resources.

Does anyone know why such happens? IMO, since there were only 20 threads, it would be about ~20 chromdriver processes at any giving moment, right ?

Thanks,

Jack

Answer (score 0):

I cannot reproduce your issue with:

1. Latest [JMeter 5.6.2](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-update-jmeter-56)
2. Latest WebDriver Sampler plugin [4.13.0.0](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/kg.apc/jmeter-plugins-webdriver/4.13.0.0)
3. Default setup of the [Chrome Driver Config](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/ChromeDriverConfig/)

   [image]

The number of `chromedriver` process instances is always equal to the number of the active threads.

So check whether your Chrome Driver Config matches mine and there are no evident errors in [jmeter.log file](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#logging) or WebDriver Sampler failures causing the thread to restart.